# MySQL group by choosing the most complete record

Tags: mysql

I have a list of records like this:

```
id    state   description   date
3340  KO      test          2016-07-27
3340  KO                    2016-07-27
3340  AQ      blalba        2016-07-27
3340  AC                    2016-07-27
```

I need to group by state choosing the most complete record between duplicated states records like the result below:

```
id    state   description   date
3340  KO      test          2016-07-27
3340  AQ      blalba        2016-07-27
3340  AC                    2016-07-27
```

Comment: what do you mean "the most complete" ? if both records have description field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work around can help you to get your expected result:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT id, `state`, `description`, `date`
FROM (
    SELECT *, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
    FROM TestTable
    ORDER BY IF (`description` <> '', 0, 1)
    ) T
GROUP BY id, `state`
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://rextester.com/LNYXX93388)</kbd>

Sample execution with the given data:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(id INT, `state` VARCHAR(2), `description` VARCHAR(100), `date` DATE);

INSERT INTO TestTable (id, `state`, `description`, `date`) VALUES
(3340, 'KO', ''       , '2016-07-27'),
(3340, 'KO', 'test'   , '2016-07-27'),
(3340, 'AQ', 'blalba' , '2016-07-27'),
(3340, 'AC', ''       , '2016-07-27');

SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT id, `state`, `description`, `date`
FROM (
    SELECT *, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
    FROM TestTable
    ORDER BY IF (`description` <> '', 0, 1)
    ) T
GROUP BY id, `state`
```